# Getting non-ascii string from server, using urllib2

Tags: python, string, unicode, ascii, urllib2

I use urllib2 to get a string from a server. 
I expect the string should be like this:

```
Bouteflika veut croire qu'il est un dirigeant hors du commun aimé de son peuple.
```

However, when I print it, it likes this:

```
Bouteflika veut croire qu'il est un dirigeant hors du commun aim\\u00E9 de son peuple.
```

This is my code to get the string:

```
import urllib2

response = urllib2.urlopen(url)

page_source = response.read()

print page_source.decode('utf-8')
```

My question is how I can get the string as expected?

Comment: what is `print repr(page_source)`?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the server sends the response.

If the response is JSON for example then it will have double quotes around it and escaped characters.

To decode that you need

```
 import json
 result = json.loads(response_text)
```

and the resulting will directly be an unicode string.

Comment: I use your code and now I get something like this:  u"Bouteflika veut croire qu'il est un dirigeant hors du commun aim\\u00E9 de son peuple." It still contains 'aim\\u00E9' instead of 'aimé'